# Gmail Script: Receive emails only during certain time of day?

Tags: javascript, email, gmail

I'm on a free-food mailing list that emails out about the location of free food around campus. However, I only want to see these emails in my Gmail inbox during lunchtime (12-2:30pm). Is there a Gmail setting or a script that I could write to make this happen For just this specific mailing list? I don't care where the emails go at the other times of day (they could be deleted, archived, stored somewhere just not seen in the inbox, etc.).

Note that I don't actually know Javascript, I just know that that's usually the language of scripts.

Thank you!

Comment: You can create a filter rule and attach a label to the emails and remove them from your inbox. Google search "Gmail filter rules"

Comment: So I only want the emails removed from my inbox if it's not in my desired time-frame. If it is 12-2:30pm, I DO want them in my inbox.